# How to listen to the load event of an <object>

Tags: angular

I'm loading an external resource in an `object` element and I want to listen to the 'load' event on a Angular 2+ Directive.

Using the @HostListener decorator the handler gets called indefinitely.
Tried listening the event in a component using the `(load)` on the template and got the same behavior - loop.

Also checked and tried the all the lifecycle hooks but none seems to trigger at the appropriate time when the load finishes.

You can easily do it with jQuery like: element.on('load', function () {})

Using Angular 4.2.3

Any suggestions/ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found out that I was experiencing this infinite loop because I was calling the `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl()` (DomSanitizer) on the url directly from the template. Something like:

`<object [data]="sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)">`

Not sure the reason behind the loop though.